# How can I add the date to the excel file title with vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, file, date

Good morning,

Currently I this code below  to create from sheet 5 some Excel files with same name at sheet. However I would like to add current date as: "List AA 30.03.2022".

```
 Sub EXCELS()

'Create excel files

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim name_file As String
 For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
 name_file = Sheets(i).Name

 Worksheets(i).Copy

 With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name_file & ".xlsx", 
 FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
Next i


End Sub
```

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name_file & " " & Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY") & ".xlsx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line `.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name_file & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with

```vba
.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name_file & Format(Date, " dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

**EDIT**
per your comment, in order to replace the file completely, you'll first need to save the old file name as a variable, then delete it afterwards.

So, replace the entire `With` block with the below;

```vba
With ActiveWorkbook
    'variable to store the old file name:
    Dim OldFileName as String
    'assign the file's current name to the variable:
    OldFileName = .FullName
    'Now save the file with it's new name, then close it:
    .SaveAs _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name_file & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    .Close
End With
'Get rid of the leftover file with the old name:
Kill OldFileName
```

Comment: What can I add to instead of saving, replace the file in the folder?

Comment: @Maya edited answer to include that.

Comment: please check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744152/how-to-update-daily-data-in-monthly-data-table-with-vba-code